# Does masking vertices help render faster?

Tags: rendering, vertices, masking

So, I typically mask vertices that are not visible when rendered, for example, in a character, the skin under the clothes. Does that help render faster or it doesn't make a difference?

Comment: Unless you're getting rid of a lot of geometry, I'd guess it has very limited effect on performance.  Maybe quicker to build and compare against BVH when you render.

Comment: You can test by looking at the elapsed render time in the top left of the render screen.

Comment: This is a question which you can easily answer yourself by comparing render times - because maybe our models are completely different from yours and an effect might have more or less impact on our models than on yours. So since you can decide if you mask vertices or not, you have all you need to get significant comparisons.